# Scala: How to capture status of all the multiple messages sent over Kafka asynchronously?

Tags: scala, callback, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using Scala to publish the messages to Kafka. 
I have list of messages to publish to kafka, possibly asynchronously. However, at the end, if there is any error in publishing at least one message, I have to capture that and take action.
I am aware of callback method, but that will work one per message. I want to accumulate or figure out the way of all such statuses and decide if nothing is failed. Something like batch status.

```
for (message <- messageList) {
    // Create a message
    // producer is created
    // I have a separate util package, having the MyCallback class with overridden onCompletion method.
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, MyMessage](config("topic"), message ), new MyCallback(config))

}
// here, I need help, to see if any of the messages sent is failed or not.
// How to capture the statuses of callback here for entire batch?


// Separate class file
class MyCallback (config: Map[String, String]) extends Callback {
    override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
     // if successful meta data, do something
     // if exception, I can log the error.

    }
}
```

Basically, I can check individual messages status in my callback class method.

How do I keep track of those statuses after my for loop is finished and take further action based on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you move `new MyCallback(config)` before the for-loop, then that will probably help.
Then you have one instance where the exceptions can be collected into.
Plus the callback object will be in scope after the loop, and you can retrieve a list of statuses

My scala is a little rusty, but I think it shows the idea

```
class MyCallback (config: Map[String, String]) extends Callback {

    private val exceptions = _ // some mutable List

    def getExceptions() { return exceptions }

    override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
     if (exception != null) {
         exceptions.add(exception)
     }
    }
}
```

Then

```
val cb = new MyCallback(config)
for (message <- messageList) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, MyMessage](config("topic"), message ), cb)
}

// TODO: check cb.getExceptions().size > 0
```

Or you can try to fail-early by checking within the loop, but that will be asynchronous and probably won't work too well